# How to split string in regex

Tags: c#, regex

```
string str = " some string ||^^ another string ||^^ shorter string
```

how do I use regex to parse str with the pattern ||^^

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: Which language are you using ?

Comment: In `[insert language here]`, use the `[insert split function here]`.

Comment: I am so sorry. I am using c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string[] lines = Regex.Split(str, "@"\|\|\^\^");
```

Comment: no sorry I do not get the desired result

Comment: Yoy have to replace "||^^" to @"\|\|\^\^"

Answer (score 1):

To split this:

```
string str = " some string ||^^ another string ||^^ shorter string";
```

You can use this regular expression:

```
string[] lines = Regex.Split(str, @"\|\|\^\^");
```